# Android - memory allocation while opening new activity

Tags: android, memory-management

let's have activity A and button in that activity, which opens activity A again. Stack looks like after couple clicks like:

A - A - A - A - ... - A

My questins go towards memory allocation. When I start  x - times activity A, would it be allocated in memory like 7 * (memory allocation of activity A) or some smaller number? What is a limit, one application can allocate in RAM?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max default heap size allowed for an application is 48MB in 3.0. But mostly depends on the device vendor.

EDIT: Don't know how to get it in adb shell. You can see the default heap size in the avd manager. Create avd for each version of android and check the value. To get it in application you can use this [api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for answer, and is there some table inidication heap size for older Android versions?

Comment: Thanks, still, my main question is still beeing unanswered.

Comment: Your question is not specific and there is no general answer to it. So i feel i have answered it. I could not answer the question you asked in your comments. The main question has been asnwered. It may not deserve a vote up but it sure is acceptable.